# How to import git repo as a node module?

Tags: reactjs, github, dataloader

I use dataloader in a React project. It doesn't work with webpack5 so I've fixed the issue directly in the node_module source code. Because this repo is not actively maintained anymore, my pr won't be merged soon.

So I've forked the project, pushed my fix, and now I'm trying to use it directly in my code without creating a special node library.

I've tried to write this in my package.json:

```js
    "dataloader": "git+https://github.com/myusername/dataloader.git#master",
```

It doesn't work. The line `import DataLoader from "dataloader";` claims that it cannot find module dataloader.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

```
"dependencies": {
   "dataloader": "git+https://github.com/myusername/dataloader.git",
}
```

**It must be in dependencies bracket**.
After added you have run `npm i`
and confirm to check-in node_modules folder.